# how to delete subdomain in whm

Tags: dns, whm, zone

When I edit a dns zone in WHM. I am able to add new entry for A record. Basically create a subdomain then points to external ip. How do I delete some subdomains? I don't find any options. When I try delete a dns zone, it deletes the entire zone, that is not what I want. Please see pictures for more detail
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the that entire entry blank say for example if you create sub domain named test.yourdomain.com then remove all entry made against host name test which will be a A record and once cleared you go down and simply click on save and this should solve your issue.